# Scala add items to ListBuffer inside recursive method

Tags: scala, recursion, scala-collections

Im trying to add items to a ListBuffer (or any other structure ?)
basically  i'm trying to create a list of **PostMD** objects  by using this method.

```
def getData(url: String, userID: String): ListBuffer[PostMD] = {
  val chunk: JsValue = BusinessLogic.Methods.getJsonValue(url)
  val postMd: List[PostMD] = for {
    x <- (chunk \ "data").as[List[JsValue]]
  } yield x.as[PostMD]

  val filtered: ListBuffer[PostMD] = 
    postMd.filter(_.fromID == userID).to[ListBuffer])

  if ((chunk \ "paging" \ "next").toString() != null) 
    getData(chunk.\("paging").\("next").toString(), userID)

  return filtered
}
```

Obviously im doing something wrong... 
what will be the best way to add item to a list inside a recursive method ?

thanks

miki

Comment: You mean something like `return filtered :: getData(chunk.\("paging").\("next").toString(), userID)`? Option B is to add a list parameter and simply add them to it and return nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often easiest to create an inner helper method to do recursion with a mutable collection.  Like so:

```
def getData(url: String, userID: String): ListBuffer[PostMD] = {
  val filtered = ListBuffer.empty[PostMD]
  def inner(url: String) {
     val chunk = ...
     val postMD = ...
     filtered ++= postMD.filter(_.fromID == userID)
     val next = (chunk \ "paging" \ "next").toString
     if (next != null) inner(next)
  }
  inner(url)
  filtered
}
```

Comment: Because you are creating  "val filtered" outside of the recursion 
 this method  is "Stack" safe ??

Comment: I think it should be filtered ++= postMD.filter(_.fromID == userID)
Because postMD.filte return a list of PostMD Objects

Comment: @MlkCode - Yes, it should; I didn't compile it (fixed now).  It's stack-safe because it's tail-recursive.  You can also pass the ListBuffer forward in each recursion to make it tail-recursive.  You can check with `@annotation.tailrec` (but the annotation only tells you when it's not, it doesn't change whether or not it actually is tail-recursive).

Answer (score 1):

You are making a recursive call, but you are ignoring its result. (In fact, any time you have an `if` without an `else` the expression inside the `if` is evaluated for side effects only).

assuming what you want is the results of the recursive call appended to your `filtered` `ListBuffer`, then perhaps change your expression to:

```
if ((chunk \ "paging" \ "next").toString() != null) 
  filtered ++ getData(chunk.\("paging").\("next").toString(), userID)
else filtered
```

And get rid of the return statement. (return statements should really be avoided, they should be never needed).

Note that this is not tail-recursive, and it will blow the stack if the discriminator you are passing to the `if` is true too man times before it is false. In order to make this tail-recursive, you might make the recursive bit an inner function which passes the list buffer you are appending to as a parameter to the recursive function.

Comment: This both blows the stack and creates a new ListBuffer every iteration, and does O(n*m) work (where m is the number of iterations) just moving contents from one collection to another.

Comment: i couldn't find or implement  a  tail recursion  example for a Listbuffer.
can you please give me example 
thanks
miki